# What is a bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, bilinear-form

I'm a CS master student and I'm reading [a paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/ECML2011LinkPrediction.pdf) that mentions the term "bilinear form". Actually the paper mentions "bilinear regression model". But I think in order to understand what a "bilinear regression model" is, I need to understand what does "bilinear form" mean. I checked the wiki page on "bilinear form" but couldn't understand.

- Can you please explain to me (in simpler ways) the idea behind 'bilinear form'?
- If you know what 'bilinear regression model' is, I would also be very thankful for an explanation as well :).

Comment: A bilinear form is a generalized scalar product. It can be realized by an intermediate (usually symmetric) matrix $\Lambda$ so that the 'generalized scalar product' of vectors $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$ is the matrix product $(x,y)=x^T\Lambda y$.

Comment: @Berci I really like your explanation since it gives me the intuition directly. However I don't fully understand. 1- Why do we need to generalize the scalar product? What is the idea behind that? 

2- The generalization is that instead of doing a scalar product between two vectors, then we do a matrix product between two vectors and a matrix? again, why to do that?

Comment: Think of it as a real valued function of two variables that is linear in each variable separately. An example would be he determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, but take the variables to be the columns. That is, $f(u,v) = \det \begin{bmatrix} u & v \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 5):

First lets cover linear regression. Using a single parameter $\alpha$ we move in a line between two points $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ with the equation

$$ \mathbf{x} = (1-\alpha)\, \mathbf{x}_1 + \alpha \, \mathbf{x}_2 $$

<sub>Here each point $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n$ dimensional vector.</sub>

This is a linear form because only the first power of $\alpha$ is used.

Now consider the case where the two control points $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ aren't fixed, but the result of linear regression themselves using a parameter $\beta$ two pairs of control points $\mathbf{x}_3$, $\mathbf{x}_4$ and $\mathbf{x}_5$, $\mathbf{x}_6$.

$$\begin{aligned} 
  \mathbf{x}_1 & = (1-\beta) \mathbf{x}_3 + \beta \mathbf{x}_4 \\
  \mathbf{x}_2 & = (1-\beta) \mathbf{x}_5 + \beta \mathbf{x}_6
\end{aligned}$$

This is bilinear form, because the location of $\mathbf{x}$ depends on two linear parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$$ \begin{aligned} \mathbf{x} & = (1-\alpha) \left( (1-\beta) \mathbf{x}_3 + \beta \mathbf{x}_4 \right) + \alpha\, \left( (1-\beta) \mathbf{x}_5 + \beta \mathbf{x}_6 \right) \\
 & =  \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \alpha + \mathbf{C} \beta + \mathbf{D} \alpha\beta \\
& & \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{x}_3 \\
  & & \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{x}_5- \mathbf{x}_3 \\
 & & \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{x}_4 - \mathbf{x}_3 \\
 & & \mathbf{D} = \mathbf{x}_3+\mathbf{x}_6-\mathbf{x}_4-\mathbf{x}_5
\end{aligned}$$

I can explain the above graphically better:

[image: pic]

All the points along the $ \overline{\mathbf{x}_3 \mathbf{x}_4}$ line have $\alpha=0$ and $\beta = 0 \ldots 1$. Similarly, the points along the $ \overline{\mathbf{x}_5 \mathbf{x}_5}$ line have $\alpha=1$ and $\beta = 0 \ldots 1$. The point $\mathbf{x}$ lies on a line with the same $\beta$ value and $\alpha=0 \ldots 1$.

It is said that there is a correspondence between the cartesian coordinates of the points and the regression parameters

$$\begin{cases}
  \mbox{point} & \mbox{parameters }(\alpha,\beta) \\
  \mathbf{x}_3 & (0,0) \\
  \mathbf{x}_4 & (1,0) \\
  \mathbf{x}_5 & (0,1) \\
  \mathbf{x}_6 & (1,1) \\
  \mathbf{x}_1 & (0,\beta) \\
  \mathbf{x}_2 & (1,\beta) \\
  \mathbf{x} & (\alpha,\beta) 
\end{cases} $$

The point $\mathbf{x}$ is bilinear mapping of the plane with coordinates $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: This is not the bilinear form concept used in the paper, which is that of linear algebra. Check on p. 443.

Comment: @YvesDaoust May I ask which textbook you mention in *Check on p. 443*?

Comment: @LeAnhDung: are you serious ? *Your paper* !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not the author of that paper :) Although the paper consists of 16 pages, it is numbered by 4xx. That's where my understanding begins ^^

Answer (score 3):

The paper says it clearly, the bilinear model is of the form $f(x_i,x_j;V)=x_i^TVx_j$.

If you consider a linear model of a single vector variable, the most general form for a function taking scalar values can be expressed as a dot product with a constant vector $f(x_i;v)=x_i^Tv$.

The bilinear form is the generalization to two vector variables. It is linear in both variables, hence its name.

$$(a\,x+b\,y)^TVz=a\,x^TVz+b\,y^TVz$$ and

$$x^TV(a\,y+b\,z)=a\,x^TVy+b\,x^TVz.$$

The generalizations to more than two variables require tensors.